# Excel sheet created with pythons xlsxwriter module runs too slow

Tags: excel

I have created a column chart with 2 series using `xlsxwriter` python module with the code below. When I open up the file in Microsoft Excel, navigating it is slow.

```
def create_2_series_column_chart(self, sheet_obj, series_1, series_2, chart_name, x_axis_name, y_axis_name, location):
    chart1 = self.output_workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})
    chart1.add_series(series_1)
    chart1.add_series(series_2)
    chart1.set_title({'name': chart_name})
    chart1.set_x_axis({'name': x_axis_name})
    chart1.set_y_axis({'name': y_axis_name})

    chart1.set_style(42)

    sheet_obj.insert_chart(location, chart1, {'x_offset': 25, 'y_offset': 10})


    series_1 = {
        'name':       ["MY_SHEET", 2, 1],
        'categories': ['MY_SHEET', 3, 0, 2+num_days_in_month, 0],
        'values':     ['MY_SHEET', 3, 15+2*ix+1, 2+num_days_in_month, 15+2*ix+1],
        }

    series_2 = {
        'name':       ["MY_SHEET", 2, 2],
        'categories': ['MY_SHEET', 3, 0, 2+num_days_in_month, 0],
        'values':     ['MY_SHEET', 3, 16+2*ix+1, 2+num_days_in_month, 16+2*ix+1],
        #'data_labels': {'value': True, 'position': 'top'}
        }

location = ["A", "J", "S", "AB"][ix]+ "54"
self.create_2_series_column_chart(self.my_worksheet, series_1, series_2, "CHARTS", 'days', 'count', location)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How slow is too slow? Have you done profiling? Do you know what line of code the bottleneck is on?

Comment: The code itself does not run slow. Something is wrong with the charts. After the excel file is created, I open the excel file, I go to sheet that contains the chart. But navigating in that sheet is too slow.

Comment: Navigating with `xlsxwriter` or with Excel?

Comment: navigating with excel

Comment: Questions about Excel are off topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: but the excel is created with python's xlsxwriter module...

Comment: excel is not slow. why did you change the question title??

Comment: Your question isn't about Python, it's about Excel.

Comment: No, it is about python xlsxwriter module

Comment: In addition to the chart, do you generate other content ?

Comment: Yes I write a lot of stuff (only numbers, texts and colorings) in that sheet and other sheets. After the program ends, I open the excel but the sheet contains the  chart runs too slow

Comment: But all other sheets run fast. Only the sheet containing the chart is slow. It seems the chart is constantly calculating something, because the bars on the charts are flashing as I scroll in the sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XlsxWriter creates charts in exactly the same way that Excel does and there are over [200 comparison tests against chart spreadsheets created in Excel](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/tree/master/xlsxwriter/test/comparison) to verify that. So, in theory there isn't anything that XlsxWriter is doing that would produce slow charts. Also, no-one else has reported any similar issues and the charting feature in XlsxWriter is used quite heavily.

Nevertheless, you are clearly seeing a issue so here are some things to look into:

1. Check the data ranges that the chart is using to plot the data. In Excel right click on the chart and choose "Select Data". Then verify that the data being plotted is correct. In particular look for an accidentally long data range or a data range that contains incorrect data.
2. Save the file in Excel, close it, and then re-open it. In this case do you see the same behaviour?

If both of those don't highlight the problem or give you further clues then you can [submit a bug report](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues). However, that will need to be a small, complete, working example that demonstrates the issue. A code snippet such as the above isn't enough information to find an issue like this.

P.S. I am the author of XlsxWriter.

Comment: Sir, I am sorry to bother you, I noticed I have made a mistake in my code, it seems I have created the same chart on the same location for 100 times one on top of other in a `for` loop. That was why the sheet was running too slow. I couldn't notice it until I dragged the chart on the top to another location. Best regards

Comment: But there is another thing, when you click on a chart series in Excel, the data range is highlighted with blue/green boxes, right? It doesn't happen with charts created with xlsxwriter module. Any ideas?

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. *Q. It doesn't happen with charts created with xlsxwriter module*. A. Yes, it does. You can't post screenshots in comments but if I could then it would look like you describe. Try one of the [Chart Examples](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/chart_examples.html) in the docs. As I said above, XlsxWriter charts are exactly like Excel charts and should behave the same.